# jasmine install error (Rails 3.2.8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jasmine

I am trying to initialize a project for Jasmine on RoR 3.2.8, Ruby 1.9.3, OS Linux Mint 13 Mate. Hope for your help.

```
rails g jasmine:install
```

After that i get an error:

```
/home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/jasmine-rails-0.2.2/config/initializers/sprockets.rb:6:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Jasmine::Config (NameError)
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/shults/rails/developers/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
from /home/shults/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: do you have jasmine in your Gemfile?

Comment: Of course i have. In my Gemfile next presents gems: jasmine, jasmine-rails, guard-jasmine,  jasminerice, ...

Comment: Is it in :development,:test group?

Comment: Yes. You are they in these groups.